# Opengl прозрачность

Tags: qt, opengl

Не получается сделать объекты полупрозрачными. Есть прямоугольник, внутри него должен быть другой прямоугольник, использовав glBlendFunc стороны прямоугольника действительно становятся прозрачными, но находящийся внутри объект все равно не видно. Проверял с помощью `glPolygonMode (GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);`, объект точно находится внутри а не где-то за границами. Объекты рисуются с помощью массивов вершин. Полупрозрачность реализую так:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
//вызов объекта через glCallList
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обычно используется `glblendfunc(gl_src_alpha, gl_one_minus_src_alpha)`. Попробуйте.

Comment: Во впрых лучше использовать формулу смешивания из коментария #1, также рендер пересекающихся полупрозрачных объектов зависит от порядки отрисовки. Т.к. при каждой отрисовки вы модифицируете  Z-буффер. Скорее всего вам надо отключить запись в него для полупрозрачных объектов и полупрозрачные обеъекты отрисовывать последними и в порядке от дальнего к ближнему.

Comment: может кому то поможет, есть семейство алгоритмов, они не простые но помогают рисовать полупрозрачные объекты в любом порядке: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-independent_transparency

Comment: http://casual-effects.blogspot.com/2014/03/weighted-blended-order-independent.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

В OpenGL нет теста глубины для прозрачности или я про него не знаю. В идеале вы сами должны его сделать. Но есть способ немного проще. Если у вас Один обект внутри другого и внутренней не видно то нужно их отрисовку поменять местами.

Например вы рисуете

```
Рисовать Кубик 1
Рисовать Кубик 2
```

И не видно того что внутри значит нужно сделать так

```
Рисовать Кубик 2
Рисовать Кубик 1
```

И теперь будит видно тот что в сиредине.

то же с полигонами может происходить

Comment: Насколько я помню буфер глубины есть, просьо включить надо

Comment: @Maxgmer для плотной геометрии - да. А вот OIT (Order Independent Transparency) или аналога, из коробки, нету.